# Documentation structure

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Most documentation I find the most helpful tends to be organized in some kind of a tree-like structure. While there is obviously the ability to break information up by tags, and then even more by topics, at that point I feel like I'm met with a wall of examples. Obviously we could break topics up into smaller topics, but in many ways you instead end up with a wall of topics in lieu of a wall of examples. I would love to see a little more nesting capability or flexibility for the organization of information. Forgive me if I'm not seeing the complications associated with that setup, or am not grasping the vision of what Documentation should be. Is this something that has been considered already?